# How can I multiply two vectors in NASM x86 assembly?

Tags: x86-64, nasm, intel, sse

I am trying to multiply two vectors of floating point values in assembly code. I am using NASM preprocessor on Intel x86_64 architecture.

Recently I have learned about SSE extension for Intel assembly, so I was trying to implement packed multiplication using SSE instructions and tail recursion. Here is my function:

```
mul:
    movdqa xmm0, [rdi]
    movdqa xmm1, [rsi]
    mulps xmm0, xmm1
    movdqa [rdi], xmm0
    add rdi, 16
    add rsi, 16
    sub rdx, 4
    cmp rdx, 0
    jg mul
    ret
```

It multiplies two vectors value by value and saves results into the first vector. Pointers to vectors are stored in `rdi` and `rsi` registers accordingly, size of both should be written in `rdx`.

The program written above catches segmentation fault on the second instruction. I think I am using SSE incorrectly.

Is there any other way to use packed multiplication? Or am I just doing something wrong here?

Comment: Please post a minimal, reproducible example, in particular the code that calls `mul`.

Comment: If `movdqa xmm1, [rsi]` segfaults, `[rsi]` probably not 16-byte-aligned. Just use `movups` instead.

Comment: Use a debugger to look at the pointer value, especially RSI.  That will tell you if the fault was due to misalignmnet.